# Cual es el tipo de valor para tener un double positivo

Tags: c#, double

Me pidieron investigar cual es el dato que tengo que utilizar para que solo se acepten valores de tipo double positivos. Algo asi como el uint en donde solo acepta numeros enteros positivos

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y que fue lo que investigaste hasta ahora? cual seria la duda?

Answer (score 0):

creo que estas en lenguaje c#, como tal no existe una clase de datos primitivos con el mismo rango de double sin signo , pero creo que te puede ayudar el tipo ulong su rango de valores aceptable 0 a 18.446.744.073.709.551.615. Equivale al tipo de datos System.UInt64 de la plataforma .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta es algo ambigua pero si lo que quieres es que despues de la declaracion quieras
que tu numro sea positivo esto lo pudes hacer obteniendo su valor absoluto.

```
 static void Main()
    {
        //
        // valores absolutos.
        //
        int value1 = -1000;
        int value2 = 20;
        int abs1 = Math.Abs(value1);
        int abs2 = Math.Abs(value2);
        //
        // resultado
        //
        Console.WriteLine(value1);
        Console.WriteLine(abs1);
        Console.WriteLine(value2);
        Console.WriteLine(abs2);
        //
        // para numeros double
        //
        double value3 = -100.123;
        double value4 = 20.20;
        double abs3 = Math.Abs(value3);
        double abs4 = Math.Abs(value4);
        //
        // salida
        //
        Console.WriteLine(value3);
        Console.WriteLine(abs3);
        Console.WriteLine(value4);
        Console.WriteLine(abs4);
    }
}

Output

-1000   //inicial

1000     (valor absoluto)

-100.123
100.123  (Absolute value)
20.2
20.2     (Absolute value)
```